# Перестало переводиться [mcve]

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии, mcve

Пишу в комментах `[mcve]`, а там английский текст ссылки вместо русского.

> [image]

Comment: Ссылка на русскую справку, а текст на английском, да.

Comment: А какой раньше текст был?

Comment: Релевантный холивар на en.SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но вроде как эта строка за это отвечает.

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12165

Не помню, какой текст раньше был. Пока предложил:

> минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Он и был, ага .

Comment: @andreymal ну, ждём апрува и выкатки тогда)

Comment: Проверяем: [mcve] Хм.. Или на мете не работает?

Comment: @Qwertiy угу, только на основном сайте, видимо.

Comment: Ну, теперь без «самодостаточного» всё же должно быть. Искажать перевод не стоит.

Comment: Когда ждать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/986333/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-js#comment1662246_986333

Comment: @Qwertiy это к Николасу. Теоретически сегодня должна новая сборка в мастер выйти.